# Which of these two dimensional array are advantageous to use and why?

Tags: c++, c, caching

In a facebook group, I saw a question like :

**If a row dominated two dimensional array in the following which one is advantage and why?**

```
a) for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
      for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
           temp=temp+a[i][j];

b) for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
      for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
         temp=temp+a[i][j]
```

From my point I can see there is no difference in the above two statements. And I guess these both are same.

Correct me if am wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference in theory.

The practical advantage is in cache locality. If you access locations which are far apart, you increase the number of cache misses, which in turn makes the code run slower.

Depending on your processor cache size, you would perhaps need to replace 1000 with some reasonably bigger number in order to perceive the effect.

Comment: So it;s not a technical question ;) **caching** would be the proper tag ;)

Comment: "There is no difference in theory" - there would be if `a` were declared `volatile`, which we can't rule out from the code we see.

Comment: Without loop rearrangement by the compiler, I *think* the first one can also be done in blocks using the SSE commands, which should add some more speed.

Comment: @SteveJessop : `volatile`? Can you explain it?

Comment: @Ant's: the implementation isn't allowed to change the number or the order of accesses to objects marked `volatile`. So, since the two loops access memory in different orders, there is a difference between them if the memory is volatile.

Comment: @Steve: strictly speaking, `volatile` doesn't guarantee the access order, at least [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_C_and_C.2B.2B).

Comment: @Vlad: that's talking about multi-threaded code, saying that the use of `volatile` doesn't create any order between code in different threads. It's irrelevant to this code, which is a loop running in a single thread of execution. Consult 5.1.2.3 in C99 or 1.9/6 in C++03 for the relevant guarantees.

Comment: @Steve: within the executing thread, the state _after_ execution of both fragments is the same. And the state _during_ their execution is not interesting to us, unless the array is located in some memory-mapped area etc., or the program reacts on a signal during the fragment execution. Well, let's put it this way: in the usual case of heap/stack allocation, there should be no difference.

Comment: "unless the array is located in some memory-mapped are" - right, and that's the normal state of affairs on a PC. There may be compilers for embedded targets (or other relatively simple processors) that can legally change the order of execution of `volatile` access, knowing that it is impossible to detect the difference, but that is not the usual case. In the usual case, the compiler can't change the order if it's `volatile`.

Answer (score 2):

Variant (a) is better, since it's much more cache-friendly, than (b): you access consecutive elements, so there are less cache misses. However, some compilers can rearrange your loops, so when compiled both variants might produce same machine codes.

Besides performance, there is no difference between this two variants, i.e. thay produce the same output.

Answer (score 2):

However, there could very well be extenuating circumstances.  For instance, if the numbers are both positive and negative there could be patterns to them such that one order would lead to an overflow (or loss of precision if floating point) where the other would be much better behaved.

Answer (score 1):

When the CPU wants to read data/code from the memory, chunks of data or moved from the memory to cache. Cache is much faster than RAM and much more expensive, so you have little of it. The idea behind this is that usually when you read one part of memory, you probably read other parts that are close to it.

In method a, you read the array row by row, and therefore you keep the locality. That is, on the first read from a row, the row is loaded in cache, and the rest of the row is read from cache (cache hit), so you have a high cache hit rate which is good.

In method b, you are deliberately accessing the array in a non contiguous way, so you get a lot of cache misses, and you need to keep reading from memory all the time.

Answer (score 0):

According to me The Correct One is 'A' :Because when we use array of 2-D it is easy for assessment Of element Row by Row to cache ,than Column by Column,
Since Cache  is used for fast Assessment  ,if more hit than it behaves fast so first one is Correct,
         Thanx
             Have a nice day.

Comment: I think your're on the right track, but your answer is really hard to understand.